# How to find if a process has fully loaded

Tags: c#, wpf

In my current project I need to send keys to a process that I have launched (I don't have any control within this process though, it is third party). Now to get these commands through, the process, EA's Origin, has to be on its main screen (that is, fully loaded after Login).

Now, I don't know how I could detect when this point has been reached. I've tried waiting for input idle, but input idle is achieved a long time before the point where I can send keys.

Is there some other method I could use to detect when the program has reached this state? I thought maybe I could detect (if) when the application signals it itself, but I'm not sure how I could find if it does signal at all, or what it signals to listen for it.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: For the reasons you've already observed, this type of UI automation is exceptionally delicate and highly prone to error. Rather than hacking together a fragile solution involving `SendKeys`, I strongly suggest that you investigate alternative approaches.

Comment: It's not 'SendKeys' I'm having trouble with, that was only a side thought for how I'll handle communicating commands to the process (I'm probably going to use pinvoke). I'm just trying to find a way to know effectively the state at which the process is. I do agree though that this would be a fragile solution and if anything, hacked together.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforinputidle?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 1):

If the main window has a distinct title you could [enumerate windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows) repeatedly and wait until the process main window appears.

BTW - I have had some bad experience with send keys (sometimes keys did not get through), and I found that combining Send Key with reading the process UI (again - enum windows) works best.

Comment: The link is dead

Comment: link updated in answer

Answer (score 1):

Is there any visual indicator in the application, such as specific label text, that shows up when it is ready to accept input?  If so you may be able to use the [windows accessibility API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (via P/Invoke) to watch for this and use it as a trigger.  It might also be possible to use the API to watch for when the actual input control gets focus.  You can even use the API instead of `SendKeys` to get more reliable interaction.